# Calling by reference creates key index

Tags: php, arrays, function

Calling a function which takes the parameter as a reference with an array with a key that does not exist, modifies the array so that the key exists later on.

```
function test(&$x)
{
}

$array = array();

print_r($array);
test($array['foo']);
print_r($array);
```

---

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [foo] => 
)
```

Why this happens and can I do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is created when you try to pass it to the function:

```
test($array['foo']);
```

You want to pass it by reference, so it has to exist. PHP will create it for you (but I guees it should throw a Notice if you have them enabled).

I would rewrite the function and pass the array and the key separately:

```
function test(&$array, $key)
```

and use it like this:

```
test($array, 'foo');
```